# Error while creating Android project

Tags: android

I downloaded Android Studio, but somehow I can't create a project! Whenever I try to create one the program raises this error: http://postimg.org/image/6cg46kpsj/

What is the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In order to develop android project you can download Eclipse ..that is simpler way ti create android projects ....i will give you a link from where you can download a sdk package you just download it extract it and start developing android projects..

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html